# How can I use optimize.portfolio from portfolio analytics library

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to use the Portfolio analytics library to create and optimize a portfolio

The first step is to create the portfolio specification

`port_spec.minES <- add.objective(portfolio=port_spec, type="risk", name="ES",  arguments=list(p=0.925, clean="boudt"))`

Than I am running the optimizer

`opt_minES <- optimize.portfolio(asset_returns, portfolio = port_spec.minES, optimize_method = "ROI",trace=TRUE )`

However I got this error

Error in clean.boudt(na.omit(R[, column, drop = FALSE]), alpha = alpha,  : 
  requireNamespace("robustbase", quietly = TRUE) is not TRUE

This is the traceback

5.stop(simpleError(msg, call = if (p <- sys.parent(1L)) sys.call(p)))

4.stopifnot(requireNamespace("robustbase", quietly = TRUE))

3.clean.boudt(na.omit(R[, column, drop = FALSE]), alpha = alpha, ...)

2.Return.clean(R = R, method = clean)

1.optimize.portfolio(asset_returns, portfolio = port_spec.RiskBudgetES, optimize_method = "ROI", trace = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that package `robustbase`is not available. You'll need to install it:

```
install.packages("robustbase")
```